# Create a simulation study using R to compare the accuracy (95% capture rate) and the lengths of the Chi-Squared confidence intervals

Tags: r, confidence-interval, variance

The minimum length confidence bounds for a normal population variance for chi-squared distribution is 
[image: enter code here]

Are they right?

GOAL: Create a simulation study using R to compare the accuracy (95% capture rate) and  the lengths of the Chi-Squared confidence interval: typical and minimum length. Then, find out how far off the typical interval from the minimum length one.

The following is my R code for stimulation and I want to make sure they are right and they are readable. Could anyone give me some comments on them?

```
# First we produce a sequence of numbers (labeled D for "derived") that will be 
# used in the quantile function to test potential upper and lower bounds for our 
# derived criteria. XAD will be the lower bound.#

n=10
start=3.283
max=3.284
interval=0.0001
XAD=seq(start,max,interval)


# Next we transform that sequence into a set of quantiles using the 
# cumulative distribution function. QXBD, the complementary quantile 
# for a 95% confidence interval, is then produced#

pchisq(XAD,n-1)->QXAD
QXBD=QXAD+.95


# Using the quantile function, we convert the upper bound quantile (QXBD) 
# into an upper bound.#

XBD=qchisq(QXBD,n-1)


# We then create an error term for the derived condition in order to determine 
# which upper and lower bounds have acceptably low error, because 
# we expect a^2*dchisq = b^dchisq#

Error=abs(XBD^2*dchisq(XBD,n-1)-XAD^2*dchisq(XAD,n-1))
Error<0.0005
XAD
XBD




# For further interval length analyses, we choose the bounds that have 
# acceptably low error. These are bolded.#

XAD=3.2836 
XBD=26.07998



# Here we produce a set of random normal variables. The upper and lower bounds for 
# the standard "symmetric" confidence interval are derived with the quantile function
# Variables and constants denoted with an "s" represent "standard," as in the 
# symmetric 2.5th and 97.5th quantile confidence interval#

ns=10
rnorm(10,0,20)->NORM
var(NORM)->VAR
qchisq(0.025,ns-1)->XAS
qchisq(0.975,ns-1)->XBS



# Finally we calculate the confidence interval bounds, using (n*V/a - nV/b) 
# for both derived and standard intervals.#

(ns)*VAR/(XAS^2)->UBS
(ns)*VAR/(XBS^2)->LBS
(n)*VAR/(XAD^2)->UBD
(n)*VAR/(XBD^2)->LBD



#Our final result is the difference in interval lengths between the 
#standard and derived intervals#

(UBS-LBS)-(UBD-LBD)
```

Comment: Oh dear god, please never use the right assignment operator `->`

Comment: @user12202013 It would be better for the OP if you clearly explained the reason for your objection.

Comment: @Glen_b, good point. The `=` assignment operator (which I also dislike) assigns from right to left, but the `->` operator assigns left to right (obviously). This is inconsistent behavior. You can actually show that `->` is parsed as `<-` by trying `quote(x -> y)` and seeing that R will return `y <- x`. If you do a search for R style guides, you will find a lot of good tips for writing good, readable code. Most style guides I have seen suggest using the `<-` operator, and unfortunately many do not even address the `->`, `<<-`, or `->>` operators (probably to reduce confusion).